How to get a direct download link to an Excel Online file with Authentication?
I have some Excel 365 files online. Some are shared with EVERYONE, and some are shared directly with me.
I want to have a local copy to them to apply some macros over them.
The share link is for VIEW ONLINE, and I have to press the {File>Create a Copy>Download a Copy} to get a copy.
I did some research and found that changing the "/edit?" to "download.aspx" downloads the file directly. However, this works only for files shared with everyone; it doesn't work for files with authentication!
The URL of the file shared with everyone is on the form:
https://onedrive.live.com/edit?id=608A1D969CB0589D!1024456&resid=608A1D969CB0589D!1024456&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!APgKtD3AX8uFMm4&wdo=2&cid=608a1d969cb0589d

Its direct download link is on the form:
https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?id=608A1D969CB0589D!1024456&resid=608A1D969CB0589D!1024456&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!APgKtD3AX8uFMm4&wdo=2&cid=608a1d969cb0589d

On the other hand, the file with the authentication link is on the form:
https://onedrive.live.com/edit?id=922...05E!152&resid=922...05E!152&cid=922...05e&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&redeem=aHR...too.long code.here...MjI&migratedtospo=true&wdo=2

But when I changed the edit? flag to download.aspx, it failed! I tried to change the migratedtospo to False and to change the wdo flag to 0 or 1, but I failed.
I also tried to add the ?download=1 flag, but it also failed, giving me the error message:

"This item might not exist or is no longer available This item might
have been deleted, expired, or you might not have permission to view
it. Contact the owner of this item for more information."

Is there any way to have a direct download link for the authenticated files?
